# angular2-cli gives @multi styles error

Tags: css, angular, styles, angular2-cli

I started using angular2-cli recently and created a new project. I wanted to use bootstrap in my project hence I installed bootstrap and then wanted to import the bootstrap css file like it is shown in the the angular2-cli guide here. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation
After running ng serve I get the following error.

> ERROR in multi styles Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '/home/krishna/angular2_migrate/webui/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   in
>   '/home/krishna/angular2_migrate/webui/node_modules/angular-cli/models'
>   @ multi styles

What am I doing wrong ?

Information about angular2-cli version

```
krishna@Krishna:~/angular2_migrate/webui$ ng version
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.17
node: 4.4.3
os: linux x64
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add ../ before path.

In angular-cli.json,

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
```

**Update**

In angular7, there is angular.json file and you do not need to add ../ before path

Comment: Almost worked for me. It worked only when I used `"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: @MWB solution worked for me, placing "../" before path is throwing error, so replaced with "./"

Answer (score 9):

In Angular 7 the file is called 'angular.json'.

Make sure you got the right extension set for the "styles" option.
In my case I installed the Angular CLI with the SCSS option but the extension was set as SASS by default.

```
       "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss" // default was: src/styles.sass
        ],
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I am using **Angular 6** so my filename is `angular.json`, but I was able to resolve the similar issue by removing the "../" path that it was asking for.
Below is my setup for adding bootstrap and jquery to my angular app.

```
   "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ],
        "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
      ]
```

**Note:** for jquery i needed the "../" while bootstap did not require it.

Alternate based on issues I had:

```
    "styles": [
          "src/styles.css", 
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
       ],
    "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", 
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
      ]
```

Also, this article holds multiple alternate options on setting it .

https://medium.com/@rogercodes1/intro-to-angular-and-how-to-setup-your-first-angular-app-b36c9c3ab6ca

Answer (score 2):

give the path like `"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` not like
`"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

```
"styles": 
[
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was was because i had

```
    "styles":[
      "styles.css"
    ]
```

in my .angular-cli.json

i solved it by manually typing the path of my all SCRIPTS and CSS ..i.e for example

```
    "styles":[
      "styles/bootstrap.scss",
      "styles/app.scss",
     ]
```

Paths in angular-cli.json are relative to the project root (src/ normally). For instance, you have the src/styles.css file, but in angular-cli.json it's listed only as styles.css.

Answer (score 1):

give the path like "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" not like
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

```
"styles": 
[
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to angular.json

navigate to styles and add another entry for bootstrap.min.css like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is the fix for me.
in you current directory you have a hidden file called .angular-cli.json
open that and change the "style.sass" to "style.css:
run ng build and you are done.

BEFORE:
[image]
AFTER:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution below worked for me, as it seems there is a bug in bootstrap 4.0:

```
npm uninstall bootstrap --save
```

then install

```
npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but I solve that issue by giving full path of the file
like below

`"styles": 
 [                "F:/Angular2Projects/Angular/myapp/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"F:/Angular2Projects/Angular/my-app/src/styles.css"
 ],`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the below mentioned code in **style.css**

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following in your {}angular.json file should work perfect.

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css" ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in angular 7 after installing primeng

I removed ./ from path in angular.json file
rename "src/styles.scss" from "src/styles.css" and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

In file angular.json , I changed styles.sass to styles.scss .

I build successfully

that is navigate to src folder and see the extension of styles file

change it accordingly in angular.json styles object

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by uninstalling bootstrap

```
npm uninstall bootstrap --save
```

and then, installing it again

```
npm uninstall bootstrap --save
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Full physical path to be given for node_modules .I have given full physical
path for the css file and finally solve the issues

Comment: Could you please include the css file and the path in your answer?