# Angular showing style scss error even with proper paths in angular.json

Tags: angular, sass

Am trying to use bootstrap and have 1 styles.scss file to compile all the of its css. I have added those paths to the angular.json but still get the following error:

> ERROR in multi ./src/scss/styles.scss
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve '/User/Project/src/scss/styles.scss' in
>   '/Users/Project'

I have read many posts such as:

- [ENOENT: no such file or directory for node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366935/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-for-node-modules-jquery-dist-jquery-min-js)
- [angular2-cli gives @multi styles error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025762/angular2-cli-gives-multi-styles-error)

They all point out that in the angular.json file the paths are absolute basically. However I have made those changes, believe that the paths I entered are correct but still get this error.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong here?

Angular.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/expoapero-front",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            ],
```

Absolute paths to both files mentioned in the error message:

- src/scss/styles.scss
- node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in src/scss/styles.scss? and if so have you checked for errors in the code?

Comment: The file exists with this path. What kind of errors in the code should I be looking for? The one I see in the console as well as in the terminal is the one in the question. I don't get anything else...

Comment: You can try removing all the code from the file. Alternatively you could try move the file to src/styles.scss, and see if it runs from there. From what you have shown it should work, so I think there is something somewhere else. You could also try create a stackblitz to share and debug

Comment: if you can share your code on github i would love to take a look

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your node_modules folder.
bootstrap is not comes by-default. please check package.json for

```
    "dependencies": {
...
    "bootstrap": "^<version_number>",
...}
```

otherwise you need to install bootstrap by following command:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

similar thing for jQuery as well.

Comment: I did install bootstrap and I can find it in the node_modules folder. It is also visible in the package.json.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

Do you see bootstrap folder in node_modules ? And did you already install required package ?

Secondly after install you need to restart your server if you modify your angular.json

Comment: I do see the bootstrap folder in the node_modules and the required package. Also I did restart the server every time I modified the angular.json.